# Médias de elementos em varias listas

Tags: python

Preciso calcular a soma de vários elementos em listas diferentes (do índice 0).

```
lista1 = [154,12,998,147]
lista2 = [897,123,998,59877]
lista3 = [3,789,111,555,699]
```

Essa seria a forma simplista:

```
soma = lista1[0]+lista2[0]+lista3[0]
```

mas preciso extrair os valores e aplicar os métodos `rolling().sum()`

```
lista4 = pd.Series([154,897,3])
lista4.rolling(2).sum()
```

algo assim !!

Comment: Precisa somente no índice 0 ou em todos?

Comment: somente o 'zero'

Comment: E qual exatamente é o problema de acessá-los diretamente, como fez no exemplo?

Comment: A lista original é multidimensional, quando eu tento acessar os valores que preciso por índice (exemplo[0][0]) e adicionar a uma lista externa, a mensagem de erro: Objeto 'NoneType' Não é subscrito.

Comment: Não está muito claro qual é o problema - seria legal se você adicionasse código demonstrando exatamente o problema que você está tendo, com a mensagem de erro. Do jeito que você fez parece ok

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem uma lista de listas:

```
lista1 = [154,12,998,147]
lista2 = [897,123,998,59877]
lista3 = [3,789,111,555,699]

listas = [lista1, lista2, lista3]
```

Você pode criar uma lista com os primeiros elementos fazendo:

```
primeiros = [lista[0] for lista in listas]
```

Assim, `primeiros` será a lista [154, 897, 3].

Como sugerido nos comentários, uma possibilidade é definir uma função que retorne os valores de um determinado índice das listas:

```
def get_on_index(*listas, index=0):
    return [lista[index] for lista in listas]
```

Assim, se precisar de todos os valores que estão no índice 2, bastaria fazer:

```
valores = get_on_index(lista1, lista2, lista3, index=2)  # [998, 998, 555]
```

Comment: Boa resposta! Para ficar perfeito seria só substituir `listas = [lista1, lista2. lista3]` por `listas = [lista1, lista2, lista3]`, acho que você acabou colocando um `.` onde queria colocar uma `,`. Melhorando ainda mais, seria talvez criar uma função para o laço e ao invés de passar o `0`, você recebesse como argumento. :D

Comment: Esse é o conjunto de dados que eu tenho: data = pd.DataFrame([[['01-09-2018',1,111,100],['01-10-2018',1,111,200],['01-11-2018',1,111,299]], [['01-09-2018',1,222,54],['01-10-2018',1,222,30],['01-11-2018',1,222,90]], [['01-09-2018',1,333,1002],['01-10-2018',1,333,950],['01-11-2018',1,333,100]]]). Dentro de cada linha preciso do ultimo valor de cada lista/célula para aplicar a formula rolling(). Como no exemplo, eu preciso fazer a soma do 100 + 200 +299 (da primeira linha);